# IBM CLI Driver - Invalid argument value

Tags: windows, db2, odbc

I've recently setup an IBM DB2 Express C on my 64-bit server machine (Windows Server 2008). Before this, I've also set up the same thing on my 32-bit local machine (Windows 7).

I have a program on my local machine that uses ODBC to connect to said database. During the testing / development phase, I used the my local machine to house both the program, and the server, as I needed the portability. I could set up the ODBC fine on my local machine (although whether to use the normal or the DB2COPY1, I don't know), but upon setting up the connection on the program, it returns the error:

[IBM][CLI DRIVER] CLI0124E Invalid argument value. SQLSTATE=S1009

[image: FAIL]

Here's a shot of the local ODBC:

[image: SUCCESS]

Which is fine. I've tried using either of the IBM ODBC, to no avail.

[image: TWINS]

Of note is that, upon using either one, I see no option to point the ODBC Connection to the server machine, either via IP Address or anything. Is there something else I can do, or am I stuck with using the local machine to contain both the program and the database? Ideally, the 32-bit local machine contains the 32-bit application, while the 64-bit server machine runs the database.

[image: YOU SHALL NOT PASS]

That said, my primary concern is figuring out what the error means, and how I can fix it. Figuring out how to get the program to work with the database over the network can come later.

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Press that Add button in your last screenshot - that as where you put in the server settings. Some help here: http://fandry.blogspot.ca/2010/11/database-alias-and-db2-odbc-drivers.html

Comment: Ah, yes, I tried that one just now, but it says "The database Alias URCDB already exists in either the local database directory or system database directory."

Comment: Nevermind. I just deleted my earlier local ODBC. It appears I can connect to the server machine database via ODBC. Thanks. Now I just have to figure out what that error means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [IBM reference for the error](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.cli.doc/doc/mcli00124e.html):

> CLI0124E
>
> Invalid argument value. Explanation
>
> The value specified for an argument was invalid. Possible reasons may
>   be a null pointer, invalid length, invalid option, etc. User response
>
> Re-examine the argument passed in to the function and determine which
>   argument is invalid.

So if the ODBC connection tests fine then your missing a parameter or something in how your connecting in your program or in the first operation you do against the database.